# Change search label in datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, abp

I'm using abp.libs.datatables.normalizeConfiguration and the default configuation for change is not working

```
 language: {
                search: "Dias restantes ",
                searchPlaceholder: "30"
            },
```

```js
var dataTable = $('#ContratoAlertaTabela').DataTable( 
        abp.libs.datatables.normalizeConfiguration({ 
            language: {
                search: "Dias restantes ",
                searchPlaceholder: "30"
            },
            serverSide: true,
            paging: true,
            'order': [[2, 'asc']],
            //order: false, //[[0, "asc"]],
            searching: true,
            
            scrollX: true,
            ajax: abp.libs.datatables.createAjax(gcaspp.contabilidade.contratoAlerta.contratoAlerta.getListAlerta,
                () => {
                    var visto = $("#ExibirVisto").is(":checked") ? "" : "true";
                    return { visto: visto };
                }),
            dom: '<"toolbar">',
            lengthMenu: [
                [5, 10, 25],
                [10, 20, 50],
            ],
            columnDefs: [
                {
                    title: '<input type="checkbox" class="alternarTodos" id="alternar" name="alternar" value="" >',
                    data: "visto",
                    orderable: false,
                    render: function (data) {
                        if (data) {
                            return '<input type="checkbox" class="visto" name="visto" value="" checked> ';
                        } else {
                            return '<input type="checkbox" class="visto" name="visto" value="" >';
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    //"visible": false,
                    title: '',
                    render: function (data) {
                        return '<input type="checkbox"  class="editado" name="teste" value="" style="display: none;" >';
                    }
                },
                {
                    title: 'Tipo',
                    data: "tipo",
                    render: function (data) {
                        return '<p class="' + data + '">' + data + '</p>';
                    }
                },
                {
                    title: 'Numero',
                    data: "numero"
                },
                {
                    title: 'Exercicio',
                    data: "exercicio"
                },
                {
                    title: 'Descricao',
                    data: "descricao"
                },
                {
                    title: 'Fornecedor',
                    data: "fornecedor"
                },
                {
                    title: 'DataAssinatura',
                    data: "dataAssinatura",
                    render: (data) => {
                        return moment(data).format("DD/MM/YYYY");
                    }
                },
                {
                    title: 'DataTermino',
                    data: "dataTermino",
                    render: (data) => {
                        return moment(data).format("DD/MM/YYYY");
                    }
                },
                {
                    title: 'DiasRestantes',
                    data: "diasRestantes"
                }
            ]
        })
    );
```

```html
<table id="ContratoAlertaTabela" class="table table-striped"></table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to do a work around in order to solve it but it still not the best way.
The solution looks like this:

```
$("#ContratoAlertaTabela_filter label").contents().filter(function () { return this.nodeType == 3; }).first().replaceWith("Dias Restantes: ");

$("#ContratoAlertaTabela_filter input").attr("placeholder", "30");
```